# Не умещается текст в TabLayout

Tags: android

Использую в своем проекте TabLayout из Material Design.
На ней находятся 3 вкладки. 3 вкладка не умещается полностью, поэтому часть слова уходит во вторую строчку.

Нету ли какого нибудь параметра, чтобы TabLayout скроллился влева - вправо, чтобы умещался текст текущий вкладки?